# For any $n$ positive integers ($n\geq 5$) exactly 3 or 4 of them are equal to each other modulo $2^m$ for some $m$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How can one prove that for any $n$ distinct positive integers, $n\geq 5$, there exists $m$ such that exactly 3 or 4 of them are equal to each other modulo $2^m$?

I tried to prove it for small $n$. For example, for $n=5$ I came up with the following heuristic argument: 3 or 4 or 5 of them are all odd or all even, so we need to exclude the ''5''-case. Assuming they all are, for example, even, we compare them modulo 4, and get the same alternative, and so on. Since we have finite number of the powers of 2, at some point we have to arrive to the desired.

But I don't know how to handle the general case. Maybe someone has a better idea?

Comment: @Arthur, thanks, I forgot to add that numbers must be distinct.

Comment: Intuitively it is obviously true.  Modulo $2^0$ everything is in the same equivalency class.  Modulo a big enough power of $2$ everything is distinct.  Going up a power of two either splits an existing equivalency class into two equivalency classes or leaves it alone.  And there is no way to split a class with five or more elements into two classes each with two or fewer elements.  So at some stage you must have an equivalency class with three or four elements.

Comment: @CuriousGuest Let me rephrase: Would $1, 5, 9, 2, 3$ be valid for mod $4$?

Comment: Yes, it surely would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume there were counterexamples. Then there is a counterexample with minimal $n \geqslant 5$. There would be one with minimal smallest number involved, and among the counterxamples with that number, with the minimal second-smallest number. Let's say the numbers are $a_1 < a_2 < \dotsc < a_n$. Then all of these numbers must be even, or all must be odd, for otherwise the subset of even numbers or the subset of odd numbers would furnish a counterexample with smaller $n$, since neither subset could have $3$ or $4$ elements, and not both could have $2$ or fewer. So at least one of the two parts contains at least $5$ elements. Since no even number is congruent to an odd number modulo $2^m$ for $m \geqslant 1$, it would be a counterexample. If the numbers were even, then $\bigl(\frac{a_1}{2},\frac{a_2}{2},\dotsc,\frac{a_n}{2}\bigr)$ would be a smaller counterexample, since $\frac{k}{2} \equiv \frac{\ell}{2} \pmod{2^m} \iff k \equiv \ell \pmod{2^{m+1}}$. So all numbers are odd. But then $(a_1+1,a_2+1,\dotsc,a_n+1)$ would also be a counterxample. And so would $\bigl(\frac{a_1+1}{2},\frac{a_2+1}{2},\dotsc,\frac{a_n+1}{2}\bigr)$. But that contradicts the minimality.

Comment: I would have thought at some stage you might want to say that if there is a counter-example then there is a counter-example with $n=5$ (a subset of the original counter-example). For me this could help justify your statement "all of these numbers must be even, or all must be odd".

Comment: Very good point that.

Comment: Actually I am not sure what I said was correct.  While I see "all of these numbers must be even, or all must be odd" is true for $n=5$ but it is less obvious for larger $n$

Comment: @Henry I need a counterexample with minimal $n$, whether that's $5$ or larger doesn't matter. If that had even and odd numbers, neither the count of even numbers nor the count of odd numbers could be $3$ or $4$, and not both can be $\leqslant 2$, so the subset of even numbers, or the subset of odd numbers gives a counterexample with fewer numbers involved.

Comment: Yes, I am coming round to agreeing with you given your recent edit